# Facebook Android SDK 4.4 throwing exceptions during login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

My login was working fine and then these exceptions started being thrown by the Facebook SDK and they are causing my app to crash.

Exception 1

```
08-06 23:35:15.672    1916-2845/com.facebook.katana W/MessageQueue﹕ Handler (android.os.Handler) {1b573833} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {1b573833} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
        at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:631)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:600)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:570)
        at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:326)
        at com.facebook.tools.dextr.runtime.detour.HandlerDetour.a(HandlerDetour.java:38)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperation.a(DefaultBlueServiceOperation.java:846)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperation.b(DefaultBlueServiceOperation.java:746)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.ops.DefaultBlueServiceOperation$3.b(DefaultBlueServiceOperation.java:691)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.a(BlueServiceQueue.java:598)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:417)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:59)
        at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:60)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Exception 2

```
08-06 23:37:36.823    1916-4440/com.facebook.katana W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue﹕ Exception during service
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:428)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
        at com.facebook.http.common.executorimpl.apache.FbHttpClientImpl.execute(FbHttpClientImpl.java:157)
        at com.facebook.http.common.executorimpl.apache.FbHttpClientImpl.execute(FbHttpClientImpl.java:145)
        at com.facebook.http.common.executorimpl.apache.FbHttpClientRequestExecutor.a(FbHttpClientRequestExecutor.java:63)
        at com.facebook.http.executors.qebased.QeHttpRequestExecutor.a(QeHttpRequestExecutor.java:102)
        at com.facebook.tools.dextr.runtime.detour.HttpRequestExecutorDetour.a(HttpRequestExecutorDetour.java:53)
        at com.facebook.http.common.RequestFlowStateController.a(RequestFlowStateController.java:110)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbRedirectController.a(FbRedirectController.java:100)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.c(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:389)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:357)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:344)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:274)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:1240)
        at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor$Dispatcher.run(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:1261)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(WrappingExecutorService.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at com.facebook.common.executors.DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:42)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My code thats using the SDK

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, this);

    dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
            .title(getString(R.string.authenticate))
            .content(getString(R.string.please_wait))
            .cancelable(false)
            .progress(true, 0).build();
}

@OnClick(R.id.login_button)
public void facebookLogin() {
    if (Utils.Operations.isOnline(this)) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, permissionsNeeded);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.no_connection),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


@Override
public void onSuccess(Object o) {
    Log.v("alarm","SUCCESs triggered");
    final LoginResult loginResult = (LoginResult) o;

    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        Log.v("alarm", "OnComplete triggered");
                    } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was occurring because I added `noHistory="true"` to my Login Activity's tag in the manifest. It seems when this is done the FacebookActivity that processes the login is unable to communicate with the activity that launched the login operation so that's leading  to the crash. To remove the activity from the history I just use the respective flags when starting the intent to navigate to the main activity.